# The Proxy server error occures when starting dotdocker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, backend

The following error occurs when I start the dotdocker `sudo dotdocker start` for my project. There was no error before and it was working successfully. However, this error appeared without any changing on the project code. The version of docker-compose and dotdocker are ***1.21.2*** and ***1.4.2*** respectively. I tried several things to solve the problem but nothing is working such as::

1 - sudo dotstart stop

2 - sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager

3 - sudo service docker restart

```
  ❯ Start dotdocker containers
    ❯ Start proxy
      ↓ Pulling codekitchen/dinghy-http-proxy:latest [skipped]
        → Image already exists
      ↓ Creating dotdocker-proxy [skipped]
        → Container already created
      ✖ Starting dotdocker-proxy
        → (HTTP code 500) server error - driver failed programming external conn
…
    ✔ Start dnsmasq
    Setting up DNS
(node:4314) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: (HTTP code 500) server error - driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint dotdocker-proxy (4e8078f31f05224f8041e65026e179114701636bbd13eb71a67382ccae860db9): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use 
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/dotdocker/node_modules/docker-modem/lib/modem.js:257:17
    at getCause (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/dotdocker/node_modules/docker-modem/lib/modem.js:287:7)
    at Modem.buildPayload (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/dotdocker/node_modules/docker-modem/lib/modem.js:256:5)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/dotdocker/node_modules/docker-modem/lib/modem.js:232:14)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1244:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:4314) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:4314) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used the `dotdocker` but from what I see from the error and specifically this part:

`tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use`

Something in your system is already using port 80 that your program wants to use.
In order to see what is using port 80 you can try:

```
lsof -P -S 2 -i "tcp:80" | grep "\(:80->.*:\|:80 (LISTEN)$\)"
```

This will give you the info and the process id in the second column.
For example:

```
apache2  1914     root    4u  IPv6   11920      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

You can then kill this process that occupying the port you want to use by:
`kill -KILL 1914`

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I still have a problem. the command that you suggested returns nothing so I used "sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN ". I tried to kill the processes, also I tried to kill them using "sudo pkill -9 apache". but every time the same process uses a different process id for the same port number

Comment: What is the name of the process that is running on port 80?

Comment: okay, the process is killed by using the process name. I used "sudo pkill apache2" command. The problem is solved now. Thanks so much for your help